# Porque o 'window.alert()' funciona na navegação entre abas e o 'window.focus()' não?

Tags: javascript, chat, alert

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
(function(){
    window.addEventListener('blur', openChat);
    window.addEventListener('pagehide', openChat);

})();
function openChat(){
           setTimeout(function(){
             alert('Há uma mensagem nova!')
             document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Nova mensagem!';
          }, 4000);
}
```

E na tag body:

```
<div id="msg">Mensagem antiga!</div>
```

Se eu mudo de aba no navegador, depois de 4 segundos, ele volta na aba que eu estava antes (focus), com a mensagem nova.

Só que eu queria poder fazer o mesmo sem usar o alert, é possível?

Tentei com o `window.focus()`. Mas nada aconteceu!
Existe alguma outra maneira?

Comment: Isso varia de navegador para navegador. No Microsoft Edge por exemplo nem o `alert` retorna a página anterior, nem o  `focus`.

Comment: Nem o foco, nem alerta. É horrível do ponto de vista de experiência do usuário quando você está navegando e uma página fica interrompendo manipulando a janela. Embora até o Google Calendar faça isso. A melhor solução é usar alguma API de notificações.  O SO mesmo tem isso no chat, onde pula uma pop-up quando você recebe nova mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe alguma outra maneira?

Bom, você pode usar uma notifications api para gerar uma notificação desktop para o usuario.

Uma pesquisa rapida pelo google, encontrei uma pergunta feita no stackoverflow americano, segue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example

Um exemplo pratico da api: https://jsbin.com/ziwod/2/edit?html,js,output